# Inheritance in kotlin, class ValueAnimator cannot be cast to

Tags: android, kotlin, subclass

I want to extend ValueAnimator class to override some methods

```
class ColorAnimator : ValueAnimator() {
    override fun start() {
        /*   ------   */
        super.start()
    }
    override fun end() {
        /*   ------   */
        super.end()
    }
}
```

then I instantiate my new class

```
val mAnimator = (ValueAnimator.ofArgb(color1, color2) as ColorAnimator).apply {
    addUpdateListener { btn.background.setTint(it.animatedValue as Int) }
    duration = 1000
    repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
    repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
}
mAnimator.start()
```

but I get this error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.animation.ValueAnimator cannot be cast to ColorAnimator

`ValueAnimator.ofArgb` returns a ValueAnimator, and ColorAnimator is its inheritor. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ValueAnimator.ofArgb` does not instantiate your new class, it always creates a `ValueAnimator` object, so you cannot cast it to its *subclass* `ColorAnimator`. That is because defining a new (sub)class does not automatically change the behavior of other methods.

The easiest solution is to add another static method to `ColorAnimator` that does what you want:

```kotlin
class ColorAnimator : ValueAnimator() {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic // if you want to use it from Java
        fun ofArgb(vararg values: Int): ColorAnimator {
            return  ValueAnimator().apply {
                setIntValues(*values)
                // ValueAnimator uses static instance of ArgbEvaluator
                // that cannot be accessed from app's code.
                // You might want to store your own instance
                // to avoid extra memory allocations.
                setEvaluator(ArgbEvaluator())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer directed me to another shorter solution. 
`class ColorAnimator(vararg values: Int) : ValueAnimator() {  init { setIntValues(*values)   
    setEvaluator(ArgbEvaluator())    }   }`
Thanks